# Computational complexity of finding a spanning tree in planar hybergraphs

Tags: complexity-theory, graphs, np-complete, spanning-trees

Using a bipartite graph to represent hypergraphs as described by Wikipedia :

> A hypergraph $H$ may be represented by a bipartite graph $BG$ as follows:
>   the sets $X$ and $E$ are the partitions of $BG$, and ($x_1$, $e_1$) are
>   connected with an edge if and only if vertex $x_1$ is contained in edge $e_1$
>   in H.
>   Conversely, any bipartite graph with fixed parts and no unconnected
>   nodes in the second part represents some hypergraph in the manner
>   described above. This bipartite graph is also called incidence graph.

Now if we assume that a hybergraph is planar if and only if it can be represented by a planar bipartite graph. **What is the complexity of finding a spanning tree in planar hybergraphs?** It is also ok if you can provide any source on how to approach this problem.

---

**Note**: It is known that the spanning tree problem of general hybergraphs is $NP$-complete, while spanning tree of $3$-uniform hypergraphs, where all hyperedges are of size $3$, has a polynomial algorithm using matroid matching [[ref](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S019688581100042X)].

**Note**: Under the bipartite representation of hypergraphs the problem of spanning tree becomes equivalent to the problem of finding a subset of vertices that induces a tree such that the tree contains all vertices of one of the bipartitions of the bipartite graph. The problem is a bit similar to the **Induced-Tree** problem defined in [this paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166218X09000663), but in this problem the induced tree must contain any set $S$ of vertices as part of the problem input. The **Induced-Tree** problem is $NP$-complete even for planar bipartite cubic graphs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in this paper ["Tree-Residue Vertex-Breaking: a new tool for proving hardness"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.07900)

> The Hypergraph Spanning Tree problem in $k$-uniform $2$-regular
>   hypergraphs is $NP$-complete for any $k≥4$, even when the incidence graph
>   of the hypergraph is planar.

Basically, they define a new problem:

> **Tree-Residue Vertex-Breaking** (**TRVB**): given a multigraph $G$ some of
>   whose vertices are marked "breakable," is it possible to convert $G$
>   into a tree via a sequence of "vertex-breaking" operations (replacing
>   a degree-$k$ breakable vertex by $k$ degree-$1$ vertices, disconnecting the
>   k incident edges)?

Proving this:

> For any k≥4, TRVB is NP-complete when the given multigraph is
>   restricted to be planar and consists entirely of degree-k breakable
>   vertices.

You can see that solving TRVB for the incidence graph of a hypergraph corresponds to solving SPANING TREE in hypergraphs. Where the incidence graph of a hypergraph is isomorphic to the bipartite representation of the hypergraph described above.